# how can i access the "Background.png" image through code?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I have the standard image "background.png" that comes with the panorama project and am trying to access it. I try this code but the image isn't detected :

```
using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    if (store.FileExists("Background.png"))
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("found");
    }
    else Debug.WriteLine("not found");
}
```

Where is the image located?

The real issue is that i add a file to the project through "add>existing item>" and wish to get it's real path.

Comment: What is the code that is used to write the image?  Are you sure it is in the user's application store, or is it in another store in isolated storage?

Comment: Maybe you mean this bug? http://blog.wpfwonderland.com/2010/10/04/incorrect-path-to-winphone-backgroundpng-in-visual-studio/

Comment: @casperOne the image is the default one from the root of the Visual Studio project, isn't that the default user store?

Comment: @BadescuAlexandru: Don't know, I don't have the project (nor am I developing for WP7), posting the code from it would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Images inside the project are not stored in `IsolatedStorage`.

```
var image = new Image
                              {
                                  Height = 29,
                                  Width = 30,
                                  Source =
                                      new BitmapImage(
                                      new Uri(@"background.png",
                                              UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute))
};
```

Comment: this should work for a database also, no?(regarding the path)

Comment: That type of URI will get you local objects. Heres a project that uses the background.png https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=ef08824b672fb5d8#!/?cid=ef08824b672fb5d8&sc=documents&id=EF08824B672FB5D8%21343

Comment: thanks for the example, but i actually need to give the path of a database that, as the background.png, is in the root of the project. Should @"/<assembly_name>;component/Database.db" work? (i.e. it doesn't seem to work)

Comment: @BadescuAlexandru Try using the path as listed in the answer (i.e. not using the assembly infO)